# How to write java program to convert html into xml

Tags: java, html, xml

I have an HTML file which contains java script and HTML tags. I want to convert that HTML file into XML file. As XML file is used only to store data. so java script will be ignored. I want to write such type of program in java.

I have tried with the sample code from 
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/162988
 but it did not work for me.

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: Could you please provide a link to html page, or paste example HTML code?

Comment: @Petr how to attach that html file along with the question?

Comment: I don't know if this possible here, you can place it on some external resource though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an existing parser for that - [Open Source HTML Parsers in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) seems to give a nice overview about available parsers.
After parsing the HTML, you can generate the XML from the objects.